# Recording Presentations with OBS and a Bluetooth Mic

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, wireless

I want to use OBS to record meetup presentations.
I can grab the laptop screen for the video and am looking for an inexpensive wireless Bluetooth microphone for the audio.

I managed to use OBS to successfully record a presentation with a cheap BT headset+mic.

I'm looking for recommendations for a BT Lavalier microphone that transmits directly to the laptop.

Most of the wireless (Lavalier) microphones that I've come across come with transmitter+receiver elements. Some of these, like the Sony ECMAW4 Wireless Microphone, apparently use Bluetooth to communicate between the two TX and RX.

However, the laptop has a built in BT receiver (and presumable more power than a battery operated device too) so I do not understand why such BT, RX-only mics are not common.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a Sennheiser [ClipMic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XIQCFWY), plug it into a cell phone, and then establish a Bluetooth connection between the cell phone and the Laptop.  I can't give any first-hand recommendations on best practices for Bluetooth audio streaming for live mics (I think most professionals prefer dedicated RF equipment to BT), but it does seem like there are options available.  [Here's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wo.voice&hl=en) one that came up in a google search for "cell phone bluetooth PC audio microphone" without quotes.

Comment: I'll have to see if phones can be connected as BT audio peripherals to my laptop. I did not consider this option.